# Predicting the growth of a social network

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, social-sciences

I am building a predictive model for the growth of the amount of users of a new p2p protocol inspired by bitcoin and I would like to use historical data collected from the growth of major social networks in my model. My specific questions are the following:

1. Does a public database exist containing growth data for major social networks?
2. Does there exist a generally accepted method for estimating contagion given specific network characteristics/assumptions?
3. I need to account for the loss of users over time and thus I need a proper way of measuring node death and its impact upon connected nodes in the model. Is there a generally accepted method to estimate this given some set of parameters?

As a side note, I am uncertain, which stack exchange to post this question in or the best way to format the question for this channel. If there is a forum one could recommend in the comments that is better suited, then I would appreciate the advice.

Comment: seems ok to me but am widely regarded as too liberal. might fly better on [stats.se] or the new [opendata.se]. it seems one could use the bitcoin blockchain to estimate growth. contagion/spread of bitcoin is highly related to social factors & not hardware characteristics & a model can only make major assumptions. also contagion is likely to vary over time. etc... also [bitcoin.se] is at times open to some other ecurrency-related questions. there was a somewhat similar recent highvoted question on [facebook spread](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83136/), stats.se somewhat an antimodel